# Redirect a method call to something with a file descriptor - asyncore

Tags: python, network-programming, file-descriptor, asyncore

We have a network client based on asyncore with the user's network connection is embodied in a `Dispatcher`. The goal is for a user working from an interactive terminal to be able to enter network request commands which would go out to a server and eventually come back with an answer. The client is written to be asynchronous so that the user can start several requests on different servers all at once, collecting the results as they become available.

How can we allow the user to type in commands while we're going around a select loop? If we hit the `select()` call registered only as readable, then we'll sit there until we read data or timeout. During this (possibly very long) time user input will be ignored. If we instead always register as writable, we get a hot loop.

One *bad* solution is as follows. We run the select loop in its own thread and have the user inject input into a thread safe write Queue by invoking a method we define on our Dispatcher. Something like

```
def myConnection.enqueue(self, someData):
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.queue.put(someData)
    self.lock.release()
```

We then only register as writable if the Queue is not emtpy

```
def writable(self):
    return not self.queue.is_empty()
```

We would then specify a timeout for `select()` that's short on human scales but long for a computer. This way if we're in the `select` call registered only for reading when the user puts in new data, the loop will eventually run around again and find out that there's new data to write. This is a bad solution though because we might want to use this code for servers' client connections as well, in which case we don't want the dead time you get waiting for `select()` to time out. Again, I realize this is a *bad* solution.

It seems like the correct solution would be to bring the user input in through a file descriptor so that we can detect new input while sitting in the `select` call registered only as readable. Is there a way to do this?

NOTE: This is an attempt to simplify the question [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857271/redirect-a-method-call-to-something-with-a-file-descriptor-python-asynore)

Answer (score 0):

stdin is selectable.  Put stdin into your dispatcher.

Also, I recommend [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) for future development of any event-driven software.  It is much more featureful than asyncore, has better documentation, a bigger community, performs better, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to understand how to use stdin.

Comment: We actually already have a working Twisted backend and it's been great! The purpose making one based on asyncore was actually specifically to get away from Twisted when python 3 came out so we could move forward. It was just recently that I noticed it runs a hot loop because of an implementation error, which prompted my post.  
While I like Twisted, I don't agree that it's well documented; if it weren't for [this](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327) I'd find it completely unusable. Still, it's awesome! (excuse the formatting, I can't figure out how to make blank lines)

Comment: Actually I think this is not a good solution. The user invokes a remote request by something like `myConnection.remoteCallName(args)` which puts the request into a queue in the asynchronous loop's thread (different from the main terminal thread). The problem is that I don't know if `stdin` will wake up the select loop before or after the request has been enqueued.

Comment: It's your program's job to keep track of details like that.  There's not really anything special about stdin, it's just another source of events.

Comment: What I mean is that with your solution the select() loop will wake up as soon as the user enters a command. This is bad because the loop will then go around and block again _before_ the user's command is enqueued, getting us right back where we started.

Comment: Once you only have a single thread, this is no longer true.  The one and only thread that is running and that called select() will wake up as soon as the user enters a command, that same thread will call the handler for stdin input, that same thread will enqueue the command, that same thread will go back into asyncore, that same thread will call writeable which will find a command in the queue (since enqueueing the command happened earlier in the execution of this one and only thread), and everything will be grand.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I must try this. Also, in fiddling around I notice that Twisted's win32 select reactor uses a 0.01second timeout by default. I would assume this is because Windows can't select on anything but Winsock sockets. I found this interesting as using a timeout to solve my problem occured to me but seemed icky. It's good to know the pros use simple solutions :)